# How to make the status bar transparent and the text color is grey?

Tags: java, android, user-interface, android-activity, statusbar

I'm trying to make the status bar completely transparent and I did successfully, but the problem is the background is white which make the status-bar text and icons unreadable!!! so I wanted to make it dark-grey and.

---

This makes the status bar transparent and keeps navigation buttons visible.

```
 if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
          Window w = getWindow();
          w.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN);
          if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            w.setStatusBarColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
          }
        }
```

---

This should make the status bar text and icons grey, but it didn't, because of the code above prevented it..! **I want to achieve both!**

```
<item name="android:windowLightStatusBar">true</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try add this into your app them

```
<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
<item name="android:windowTranslucentNavigation">true</item>
```

And then try add this into `onCreate()`

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            Window w = getWindow();
            w.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
        }
```

Comment: the above code makes the bottom navigation buttons a part of the view which's why I had to use the code in my question to prevent that from happening. see the pic https://image.ibb.co/ihf8YS/device_2018_03_05_225258.png